# Mongoose not validating type: [SimSchema]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema:

**tango.schema.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var notEmpty = [function(arr) {
  return arr.length > 0;
}, "Can't be empty."];

var TangoSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  sims: { type: [SimSchema], required: true, validate: notEmpty },
  statements: { type: [StatementSchema], required: true, validate: notEmpty }
});

var SimSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 5 },
  description: { type: String, required: true, maxlength: 140 }
});

var StatementSchema = new Schema({
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  children: { type: [StatementSchema], required: true, validate: notEmpty },
  focus: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  childrenHidden: { type: Boolean, required: true },
  simId: { type: Number, required: true }
});

exports.TangoSchema = TangoSchema;
exports.SimSchema = SimSchema;
exports.StatementSchema = StatementSchema;
```

The following test fails. It returns a `200` instead of a `400`:

```
it('Sim has no name', function(done) {
  delete testTango.sims[0].name;

  agent
    .post('/tangos')
    .send(testTango)
    .expect(400)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      var result = JSON.parse(res.text);
      assert(result.error);
      assert.equal(result.error, 'Tango validation failed');
      done();
    })
  ;
});
```

I was expecting that since the Tango object that was sent has a Sim that doesn't match the SimSchema, it wouldn't successfully create the Tango. Instead, it's creating the Tango successfully and sending back a `200`.

Why is this? Isn't `type: [SimSchema]` supposed to say, "this property has to be an array of objects that match the SimSchema"?

Comment: Are you sure your test data is correct and that the array has been emptied? I actually see no single case where the custom validator would be called, however: 1. The required attribute on the parent schema will throw an error for either an empty or non present array, 2. The sub-schema validation would kick in if elements did not match the same required rules. I think the problem here is you are trying to manipulate this as a JavaScript object when it is in fact a mongoose document. So you cannot delete things from the array like you are trying to do and the "changes" simply do not happen.

Comment: I think it might be because of the order my schemas are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the validation but in the manipulation of the object itself. You are treating this as a JavaScript object when trying to remove the "name" property from your sample data in the array, but the problem is this is not a plain JavaScript object, but a mongoose document structure instead.

The confusion is that the mongoose document attempts to "look like" a plain JavaScript object, but in fact the properties you are attempting to manipulate are actually not plain properties at all. Subsequently the change does nothing;

With the basic code to reproduce:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var childSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  children: { type: [childSchema], required: true }
});

var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);

var obj = new Parent({ name: "Homer", children: [{ name: "Bart"}] });

console.log(obj);

//obj = obj.toObject();
delete obj.children[0].name;

console.log(obj);
```

Which is going to show that despite the manipulation attempt, nothing has changed at all:

```
{ name: 'Homer',
  _id: 55fb841ce300c51e0ef842e3,
  children: [ { name: 'Bart', _id: 55fb841ce300c51e0ef842e4 } ] }
{ name: 'Homer',
  _id: 55fb841ce300c51e0ef842e3,
  children: [ { name: 'Bart', _id: 55fb841ce300c51e0ef842e4 } ] }
```

The big hint is the commented line there, since you need to change this first back to a regular object and then cast again as a mongoose document:

```
obj = obj.toObject();
delete obj.children[0].name;

console.log(obj);

obj = new Parent(obj);

obj.save(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Adding in those lines make all the difference:

```
{ name: 'Homer',
  _id: 55fb85439652ee2c0ec8800e,
  children: [ { name: 'Bart', _id: 55fb85439652ee2c0ec8800f } ] }
{ name: 'Homer',
  _id: 55fb85439652ee2c0ec8800e,
  children: [ { _id: 55fb85439652ee2c0ec8800f } ] }
{ [ValidationError: Parent validation failed]
  message: 'Parent validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors:
   { 'children.0.name':
      { [ValidatorError: Path `name` is required.]
```

You also should not need custom validators on those array fields. Simply setting `required` will throw an exception if it is omitted from the object or if just and empty array is sent. And of course if the array document content does not match the sub-schema definitions then that validation is triggered as well.

Comment: `testTango` is a JavaScript object. I'm defining `var testTango = ...` in my `beforeEach`. I tried `testTango = testTango.toObject()` but it threw an error. Good point about `required` though. How do you know that; is there any documentation for it (I looked and didn't see)?